# Find local maxima using scipy.signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I have a 1D array (A) of 64 integer values. How can I find the 2 local maxima corresponding to the values `56` and `50` (indices `10` and `45`, respectively) using the `scipy.signal` module?

At first I tried importing

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

A
array([  0.,   1.,   3.,   8.,   6.,  16.,  29.,  29.,  47.,  42.,  56.,
    44.,  49.,  40.,  34.,  34.,  26.,  24.,  25.,  21.,  22.,  24.,
    34.,  17.,  17.,  29.,  24.,  26.,  13.,  25.,  16.,  19.,  19.,
    26.,  24.,  26.,  41.,  34.,  24.,  37.,  37.,  39.,  34.,  40.,
    45.,  50.,  28.,  45.,  43.,  46.,  47.,  41.,  30.,  23.,  19.,
    15.,   9.,  10.,   3.,   6.,   4.,   1.,   1.,   0.])
```

but before I got any further I got the error message that

> "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_peaks'",

so then instead I tried importing

```
from scipy import signal
peakind = signal.find_peaks_cwt(A, widths=32)
```

but then I get the error message that

> "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable".

I still get this error message even if I first do `A.astype(np.int64)`.

Can't I use `scipy.signal_find_peaks` on an array of integer values?

Comment: @Cleb Thank you for your response! Not quite I'm afraid. I found the potential solution to use argrelextrema, but it would return all local maxima and I am only interested in a function/module who finds the two values I want (56 & 49). Actually, the documentation I found about scipy.signal.find_peaks seemed very promising so it was disappointing that it could not be loaded.

Comment: As the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) state, `find_peaks` is new in version 1.1.0. Updating scipy should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) as follows (make sure that you work with SciPy >= 1.1):

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([0.,   1.,   3.,   8.,   6.,  16.,  29.,  29.,  47.,  42.,  56.,
    44.,  49.,  40.,  34.,  34.,  26.,  24.,  25.,  21.,  22.,  24.,
    34.,  17.,  17.,  29.,  24.,  26.,  13.,  25.,  16.,  19.,  19.,
    26.,  24.,  26.,  41.,  34.,  24.,  37.,  37.,  39.,  34.,  40.,
    45.,  50.,  28.,  45.,  43.,  46.,  47.,  41.,  30.,  23.,  19.,
    15.,   9.,  10.,   3.,   6.,   4.,   1.,   1.,   0.])

peaks, _ = find_peaks(A, distance=32)
print(peaks)
# This prints the desired indices [10 45]

plt.plot(A)
plt.plot(peaks, A[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

So, instead of using `widths`, you use `distance` which defines the minimum distance between two peaks.

This will plot:

[image]

As you can see, only the two desired peaks are marked by a `x` and all remaining local maxima are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

For peak detection (1d-vectors or 2d-arrays (images)), you can use the library [findpeaks](https://erdogant.github.io/findpeaks). This library contains multiple peak detection methods.

```
pip install findpeaks

A = [  0.,   1.,   3.,   8.,   6.,  16.,  29.,  29.,  47.,  42.,  56.,
    44.,  49.,  40.,  34.,  34.,  26.,  24.,  25.,  21.,  22.,  24.,
    34.,  17.,  17.,  29.,  24.,  26.,  13.,  25.,  16.,  19.,  19.,
    26.,  24.,  26.,  41.,  34.,  24.,  37.,  37.,  39.,  34.,  40.,
    45.,  50.,  28.,  45.,  43.,  46.,  47.,  41.,  30.,  23.,  19.,
    15.,   9.,  10.,   3.,   6.,   4.,   1.,   1.,   0.]
```

**Topology method**

```
from findpeaks import findpeaks
fp = findpeaks(method="topology", )
results = fp.fit(A)
results['df']

# For every datapoint, it returns whether it is a peak or valley.

   labx   peak  valley    y   x
0      0  False   False  0.0   0
1      1  False    True  1.0   1
2      1  False   False  3.0   2
3      1  False   False  8.0   3
4      1  False   False  6.0   4
..   ...    ...     ...  ...  ..
59     0  False   False  6.0  59
60     3   True   False  4.0  60
61     0  False   False  1.0  61
62     0  False   False  1.0  62
63     0  False   False  0.0  63
'''

fp.plot()
```

[image: Toplogy method]

**Peakdetect method**

```
fp = findpeaks(method="peakdetect", lookahead=10)
results = fp.fit(A)
results['df']
fp.plot()
```

[image: Peak detect method]

**caerus method**

```
fp = findpeaks(method="caerus", params={'minperc':10, 'window':10})
results = fp.fit(A)
results['df']
fp.plot()
```

[image: Caerus method]

*Disclaimer: I am the author of this library*